# Is the prime counting function differentiable?

Tags: calculus, analytic-number-theory

Let $\pi(x)$ denote the number of primes not exceeding $x$. Is $\pi(x)$ differentiable ?

My attempt: It is well known that $\log \zeta(s) = \int_{2}^{\infty} \dfrac{s\pi(x)}{x(x^s - x)} \mathrm d{x}$ where  $\Re(s)\geq 2$. Since we can't integrate this by parts without differentiating $\pi(x)$, the answer seems to be *yes* ?

Comment: How can $\pi$ differentiable since it's even not continuous ?

Comment: "Since we can't integrate this by parts without differentiating $\pi(x)$" What does our ability to do integration by parts have to do with anything? Is it used in the proof of the identity?

Answer (score 1):

$\pi(x)$ is a nonconstant integer-valued function, so it necessarily has jumps (specifically, it jumps by $1$ at each prime and is constant between primes). It will therefore not be differentiable at each prime, and will have derivative $0$ everywhere else.